# Editing existing pdf in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I'm testing Java lib to edit existing pdf but the issue is that a can't load my existing pdf.
I have the same result with iText and pdfbox, I can load the file the data seems here(pdf weigh ko) but the pdf created is empty (nothing display).

I'm doing it on a app engine server, with the two lib I can create pdf and display it in my browser with servlet or webservice.

I'm totaly lost, try tons of code but always the same result!

iText with importedPage :

```
    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    document.open();

    // Load existing PDF
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("WEB-INF/pdf.pdf");
    document.newPage();
    PdfImportedPage page = docWriter.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.addCell(Image.getInstance(page));
    document.add(table);

    document.close();
    docWriter.close();
```

pdfbox :

```
     PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
     PDDocument sourceDocument = PDDocument.load("WEB-INF/pdf.pdf");
     PDPage templatePdfPage = (PDPage)sourceDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
     document.addPage(templatePdfPage);
     document.save(output);
```

Comment: What does "can't load my existing pdf" mean? Also, please post some of the code you have tried that doesn't work.

Comment: If only you showed us one gram of your tons of code, we'd know what you're talking about. Unfortunately, you're not telling us anything about your goal ("editing" is not a correct word in the context of PDF), nor what you mean when you say "PDF created still white".

Comment: Please upload the PDF somewhere. And post the code that you used. Your text has a contradiction: you say you have an existing PDF, but then you say it "created white".

Comment: Well, at least the op has comments from major players in the context of the mentioned libraries... Not every question has achieved that. ;)

Comment: I have add some code. I want to use a pdf as a template so firstly a try to load and return it. Next step is to edite it.

Comment: @Kingstone59 You didn't mention the correct path where pdf file is located. Check the answer I posted, It's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Get the path Using ServletContext Servlet and using PDFBOx read the pdf file and save the pdf file in `/WEB-INF/savedpdffiles/` folder.

Note: Create the folder `savedpdffiles` under `WEB-INF` folder.

See [The JRE Class White List - A Java App Engine application's access to the classes in the Java standard library (the Java Runtime Environment, or JRE) is limited to the following classes:](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist?csw=1).

Read and save PDF file in Google AppEngine.

**Code:**

```
    PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
    try {
        ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        String pdffiles = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");

        File readPath = new File(pdffiles);
        if (readPath.exists()) {
            String pdfFile = "04-Request-Headers.pdf"; // read this file to save in savedpdffiles folder
            File savedPath = new File(readPath.getAbsolutePath() +"/savedpdffiles/"); // create savedpdffiles folder under WEB-INF folder

            File readFullPath = new File(readPath.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + pdfFile);
            if (readFullPath.isFile()) {
                if(!savedPath.exists()) {
                    savedPath.createNewFile();// create new pdf file if not exits
                    printWriter.println( savedPath.getName() +" File created in -> "+ savedPath.getAbsolutePath());
                }

                PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
                PDDocument sourceDocument = PDDocument.load(readFullPath.getAbsolutePath()); // read the pdf file by PDDocument
                PDPage templatePdfPage = (PDPage) sourceDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0); // only first page is read out of 13 pages and save the first page.
                document.addPage(templatePdfPage);
                document.save(savedPath + "/" + pdfFile);
                document.close();
                sourceDocument.close();
                printWriter.print(pdfFile + " File saved to this location-> "+ savedPath.getAbsolutePath() + File.separatorChar + pdfFile);
            } else {
                printWriter.println(readFullPath.getName() + " File not exits in -> "+ readFullPath.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } else {
            printWriter.println("Path not exists -> "+ readPath.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        printWriter.print("Type of Error occured while saving the PDF file -> "+ e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You will get below error

```
Caused by:
          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Color is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    Powered by Jetty://
```

Comment: The method getServletContext() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest ? I'm on Google app engine with jersey

Comment: @Kingstone59 code updated as per google appengine code.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem, I'm using maven to build my app.
Maven corrumpt my pdf by encoding file (in UTF-8 I think).
I found this because I got .p12 file and when I what to read my lib say it was corrumpt file.

The problem now is a try to avoid this but dosn't work. (For the moment I replace file after build)

I try to add this in my pom.xml :

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.pdf</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and something was ambigious in my pom.xml, I doesn't not what it do :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```